# Redux-React trying to iterate object that is keyed by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am just learning Redux, and have run into the following difficulty.  The state object `mylist` looks like this:

```
{
  byId : {
    1 : {
      id : 1,
      name : "hello"
    },
    2 : {
      id : 2,
      name : "goodbye"
    }
  },
  allIds : [ 1, 2 ]
}
```

My component is trying to iterate the state like so:

```
<select>
 {this.props.mylist.allIds.map(function(x){
    return <option key={x} value{x}>
             {this.props.mylist.byId[x].name}
           </option>
 })}
</select>
```

The value of `x` is being pulled out successfully by the map function.  But `this.props.mylist.byId[x].name` is not resolving.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"is not resolving"*?

Comment: Hi Felix.  Thanks for the dup link.  That solved my problem.